# Bottom Corners are not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I try to set topright & bottomRight corner as follow but it is not working

**Try 1**

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.main_scroll.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight, .BottomRight],
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)).CGPath
self.main_scroll.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

**Try 2**

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.main_scroll.frame, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.BottomRight.union(.TopRight), cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(100, 100)).CGPath
self.main_scroll.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

**Try 3**

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.main_scroll.frame
rectShape.position = self.main_scroll.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.main_scroll.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomRight,.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)).CGPath
self.main_scroll.layer.mask = rectShape
```

**Thank you,**

Comment: `main_scroll.clipToBounds = true`

Comment: @Mr.Bista, still it is not working!

Comment: `main_scroll.layer.masksToBounds = true` ?

Comment: @Mr.Bista, I already tried that but it is also not working :(

Comment: The second code snippet should works as expected, I tried it on my playground...

Answer (score 2):

Try this using DispatchQueue.main.async this works for me

```
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.messageLabel.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners:[.bottomRight, .topRight, .topLeft],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height:  8))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.messageLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```